# Can a professor ask students to upload a picture ID?

Tags: confidentiality

This week I had a midterm exam which wasn’t mandatory, but the professor provided it so we could improve our grades. Along with the instructions that was listed, there was a line which says have your photo ID ready. So when the exam came, I logged into the zoom channel and I had my ID with me in case the professor wants to verify it through the Cam. The professor wasn’t there and I found myself answering the questions as it’s a maths exam and it has a time limit. Later on, I received an email from the professor saying that my submission cannot be accepted because I didn’t scan my picture ID and upload it with the exam. I told him I don’t feel comfortable uploading my ID, he insisted that I can blackout sensitive information. Is this normal ? Why would the professor ask for a picture ID to be scanned and uploaded with the exam ? I have reached out to the chairman and I am afraid that the professor would target me more.

Comment: What country is this in?  In my experience, being asked to show an ID during an exam is standard practice in larger classes.  Especially if what they're asking for is your student ID, which they issued to you.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for wanting it scanned is so that it can be checked later, rather than in real time. Whether that is reasonable or not, is a decision for the department or university to make. It might be improper to ask that a non-university ID be scanned, but the use of university documents, such as a student ID, is probably within their proper authority.

I think your position is reasonable, but not necessarily the best option. But it might also be that you didn't read the instructions completely.

However, if it wasn't clear that it should be scanned and they just assumed that you would, then you have cause for complaint.

I hope you can work out something satisfactory and that it was just a correctable misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you buffy for your answer. What triggered me is first this is an online class. So if he wants to verify the person taking the exam, probably he would use the camera and the person behind it if it matches the I’d or not. Secondly, I think this might cause racial profiling and things of this nature. I have taken a few exams prior to this, but had never been asked to scan my iD